# How to plot graph in complicated pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame about rows-transaction like:

```
 Month        Category       Quantity
 3            A              1 
 3            A              1
 3            B              1  
 4            A              1
 4            B              1
 4            B              1
```

I used groupby function to count the quantity of each category in each month

```
df.groupby(['Month','Category']['Quantity'].count()
```

Results:

```
Month   Category    
3       A           2
        B           1
4       A           1
        B           2
```

I don't know how to plot quantity graph for category ( A & B should be represented by different lines), x-axis is the time, in terms of output of groupby function. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to `unstack` and then call `pd.DataFrame.plot`:

```
df.groupby(['Month','Category'])['Quantity'].count().unstack().plot()
plt.show()
```

You get a graph with two lines, one per `Category`.

Comment: Thank you, but I have another problem. Because my dataset has many categories (8), the legend created is in alphabet order, not in quantity order, so it would be confused. How can I change the legend into quantity order for the first month only?

Comment: @Homesand I would recommend taking a look here: https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html Basically, figure out your desired order and explicitly pass it to `plt.legend`. If you have further questions, consider opening a new post.